# how to use pyinstaller with no extra file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I would like to ask if it is possible to use pyinstaller with no extra file(the '.dll' files) and other things in the output.
I tried one using on a simple script and using pyinstaller, maybe an hour ago and I'm not quite satisfied with it, it seems there are lot's of extra file, I would 'only' like to have the .exe file, and no console window.
thanks
I'm using python 2.7 and pyinstaller 3.3

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions at once as this is not suggested in SE system.

Comment: Hi just read your comment, I'm really sorry I haven't read that one, I'll edit my post now sorry man, I thought someone might find me irritating this way(posting another thread) sorry man

Comment: It's ok. Actually, I think *most* people won't get irritated for this, as it is the [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pyinstaller -F -w --clean your_python.py
```

The clean command will erase last builds.

You can try using -w or not, in my experience this can be different behaviors depending in your code.

Comment: thanks, but will that give me only one file(only exe file?)

Comment: thanks, I can't see the console window and no other "blablabla" files thanks bruv.